# Filtering a report without summary formula changing

Tags: reporting

I have a report with two groups, and a summary level field that is a calculation based on those groups
summary calculation - PARENTGROUPVAL('Sum of a field', GRAND_SUMMARY)/ RowCount
I want to show just one of those groups in a dashboard, but if i drill down, the calculation recalculates. Is it possible to filter or drill down without it recalculating?

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.